# How can I return data from MYSQL as JSON using PHP so that I can use it in on my HTML page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get data from the `mysql` database using `php` and `wordpress` which I want to convert to `json` to get all the data from my `mysql` query. I have made the call using AJAX to the `php` file that runs the `mysql` but I don't know how to convert the `sql` query to `json` and return it on my HTML page. Any help would be appreciated.

**AJAX**

```
$(document).on("click", ".get_notes", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 const notesSection = $(this).data("notes-section")
    $.ajax({
    url: WP.ajax_url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
    'action': 'notes',
    'notes_section' : notesSection
    },

    success: function(data) {
     if (data.success == true) {
       $(".notes-timestamp).text(**json data here**); // Somehow get access to all data from mysql query to use in HTML page 
       $(".notes-user-note").text(**json data here**); // Somehow get access to all data from mysql query to use in HTML page
      }
    },        
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
  if (isset($_POST['notes_section'])) {
    $notesSection = $_POST['notes_section'];

    $getNotes = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_activity_notes WHERE userId =%d AND postId =%d AND siteId =%d ORDER BY id DESC", $user_id, $notesSection, $site_id, OBJECT);
    
    $getNotesQuery = $wpdb->get_var($getNotes);
    json_encode($getNotesQuery);
    foreach($getNotesQuery as $f){
      $json_array = array(
        $f->notes
      );
    }

    wp_send_json_success($json_array);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['notes_section'])) {
    $notesSection = $_POST['notes_section'];

    $getNotes = $wpdb->get_results( 
        $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_activity_notes WHERE userId=%d AND postId=%d AND siteId=%d ORDER BY id DESC", $user_id, $notesSection, $site_id), ARRAY_A
    );

    $getNotesQuery = $wpdb->get_var($getNotes);
    $json_array = array();
    foreach($getNotesQuery as $f){
      $json_array[] = $f->notes;
    }
    $output = json_encode($json_array);
    wp_send_json_success($output);

}
```

Comment: Thank @moishy I tried your code and it returns an empty array  {success: true, data: "[]"}
data
: 
"[]"
success
: 
true

Comment: i update my answer and modified the SQL

Comment: still the same issue. it works if i remove the user_id, post_id and $note_section. Why is that stopping it ?

Comment: you need to declare the `$user_id` and `$site_id` somewhere

Comment: this has been declared too which is being passed via ajax and declared further up in my php i have posted

Comment: you are only posting `notes_section`

Comment: Hi moishy, i have solved this. I had to use the query like this -   $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_activity_notes WHERE userId = $user_id AND postId = $notesSection AND siteId = $site_id ORDER BY id DESC" ); Thank you for your help, appreciate it

Comment: It's best practice to always use prepare; The main use of it is to prevent against SQL injection

Comment: i think the Get_results in wordpress protects it from SQL injections plus I do not have any textboxes, just pulling data that is already sanatized from the database

Comment: you are sending unsanitzed data to the database in your ajax request

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use the below sql query instead of using a `prepare`

`$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_activity_notes WHERE userId = $user_id AND postId = $notesSection AND siteId = $site_id ORDER BY id DESC" );`